# Create type-annotations container for multiple variables

Tags: python, mypy

I would like to create a DataFrame[T,..] type container that can hold multiple variables defined during type annotation like this:

```
UserId = DataFrame[int] #single
```

or

```
UserIdAndName = DataFrame[int, str] #multiple
```

And then be able to use these types anywhere types are allowed:

`def get_name(x: UserId) -> UserIdAndName:`.

I could get the first example working using Generics but how to allow for multiple parameters definition I only see that working using [metaclasses + get_item slices](https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce/blob/master/dataenforce/__init__.py#L77) but that breaks in mypy.

Any solution that is pythonic and does not break mypy?

Answer (score 0):

With two TypeVar, i think that your goal can be reached just for two items, but the number of TypeVar cannot be "generic", only the type can be. Also with builtin types this is not possible: `x: tuple[int, str, ...]` is invalid for mypy.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')


class DataFrame(Generic[T1, T2]):

    def __init__(self, x1, x2):
        self.items: Tuple[T1, T2] = (x1, x2)


UserIdAndName = DataFrame[int, str]  # 2
UserIdAndYear = DataFrame[int, int]  # 2


def get_name(x: int) -> UserIdAndName:
    return UserIdAndName(x, 'name')


def get_year(x: int) -> UserIdAndYear:
    return UserIdAndYear(x, 1988)


y = get_name(11)
reveal_type(y)
y2 = get_year(11)
reveal_type(y2)
```

Answer (score -1):

For composite type signatures you can use `typing` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).